# How replace specific property value in an array's item in Helm values.yaml on command line instead of the entire array/map?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I try to override only a specific value in a `map` item inside an array in my `values.yaml`, it replaces the entire thing and makes it have only that one property. Is there a way to keep the defaults and only override part?

My values.yaml has:

```yaml
envVariables:
  - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    secretKey:
      name: creds
      data:
        - name: username
          value: root
        - name: password
          value: REPLACE_ME
```

I want to replace the password `value` *only* at the command line, but instead it changes the entire structure to only have `envVariables[0].secretKey.data[1].value`. The property `name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is gone along with everything else I didn't pass.

```sh
helm template ./testchart --set envVariables[0].secretKey.data[1].value=pass
```

Comment: Did you end up working out how to do this?

Comment: @mahgo Sort of. The only way to do it is to specify the values for every parameter in the array on the command line. So you can put all the default values in your command line for the ones you don't want to change. It's the only way since the Helm team doesn't want you to use hierarchical structures.